# Xpath for a div containing text

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I'm using selenium to execute test on a html page. I only can use xpath to locate element. I'm trying to make an xpath that allow me to locate all the div that contains a text, so i could keep the reference of these WebElement with findElements, whatever it is as long as he is not empty.
So i have this xpath :

> //div[5]/div/div[2]

And i want to locate all the div element that contains text inside this div (the div located by //div[5]/div/div[2])

I have tried different ways using text() or matches() but i can't make it work, by exemple :

> //div[5]/div/div[2]/div[matches(text(), '*', 'i')

What should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find node that contains any text simply use:  //div[5]/div/div[2]/div[text()]

Comment: Do you if this xpath will looks inside the node of the children ?

Comment: //div[5]/div/div[2]/div[text()] will only test for text within the final div and ignore child nodes;  If you want to check children too do this:  //div[5]/div/div[2]/div[//text()]

Comment: missing a dot before `//text()` ?

Comment: @Stefen - the dot is optional since the context will be on the current node already

Comment: div[text()] has saved me. +1

Answer (score 1):

`//div[5]/div/div[2]/div[contains(text, 'Your text here.')]`

The above XPath should accomplish what you're aiming to achieve.

Comment: should it be 

//div[5]/div/div[2]/div[contains(text(), 'Your text here.')]